# How to modifie this code to work on screen tap on smartphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to modify this code to work on screen tap on smartphones. it changes the item when pressed space bar on keyboard but I want it to also work when someone just taps on the touch screen.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
   if (e.which === 32) {
     $("#quote").addClass("reset");
     $("#quote").removeClass("executed");
     $("#writer").toggleClass("fade");
     setTimeout(function(){ 
       $.ajax({
          crossOrigin: true,
          url: "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
          dataType:"jsonp"
        });
     }, 1000); 
   }
});





function mycallback(json){
   var quote = json[0];
   $("#quote").html(quote.content)
   $("#writer").html(quote.title)
   $("#quote").addClass("executed");
   $("#quote").removeClass("reset");
   $("#writer").toggleClass("fade");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to bind the event with `.on()` listener and to `document` instead:

```
$(document).on('keypress touchstart', function(e) {
```

If you are interested in some library for this then [hammerjs](http://hammerjs.github.io/) is the one you are looking for.